# Order confirmation mail stopped working suddenly

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email

I am running magento 1.9.1. I was getting order confirmation emails till yesterday. Not sure what happened, all of sudden I am not getting emails for new orders. But I am getting email when I change the status of new order from pending to processing. I installed AOE scheduler to investigate. Couldn't read much from the scheduler view. Can anyone help looking at the attached AOE scheduler list view. Do I need to delete or kill any tasks. Also i don't understand why multiple core_email_queue_send_all tasks are running.
[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Make sure that your Magento cron job is running and running often enough (something like every few minutes).

Comment: http://www.aschroder.com/2015/01/sending-emails-by-queue-in-magento-1-9-1/